# Configuring Ant Design with Angular 8 and SCSS

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, antd, ng-zorro-antd

Does anyone have experience setting up Ant Design in an Angular project with SCSS styles? Setting up is not the difficult part but I'm trying to override the variables that Ant Design exposes in their design system. The problem is that they use `.less` files for their styling and I'm not sure how to use that in unison with `scss`.

I have seen some examples for React projects. But angular creates some other issues because it processes the scss files itself and I'm not sure how to get around it.

I created the project using Angular CLI.

Here's some of the code:

**angular.json**  file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ant-design-poc": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {  
              "path": "./src/custom-webpack-2.config.js"  
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/ant-design-poc",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.less"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {  
              "path": "./src/custom-webpack-2.config.js"  
            },
            "browserTarget": "ant-design-poc:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ant-design-poc:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ant-design-poc:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ant-design-poc-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ant-design-poc:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ant-design-poc:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ant-design-poc",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

**Webpack configuration**

```
const path = require('path');

const AntdScssThemePlugin = require('antd-scss-theme-plugin');

const config = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          AntdScssThemePlugin.themify({
            loader: 'sass-loader',
          }),
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          AntdScssThemePlugin.themify('less-loader'),
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /dist/,
  },
};


module.exports = config;
```

**Styles.scss** file

```
@import "../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.less"; //import ant design style file

$primary-color: #0077ff;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ant-design-poc",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^7.5.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^8.4.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.20",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "antd-scss-theme-plugin": "^1.0.8",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "sass": "^1.23.7",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

This is the error that I get when I try to build the project:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.less (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--16-3!./node_modules/style-loader/dist!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--20-1!./node_modules/antd-scss-theme-plugin/build/dist/lib/antdLessLoader.js??ref--20-2!./node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.less)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


var content = require("!!../css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--20-1!../antd-scss-theme-plugin/build/dist/lib/antdLessLoader.js??ref--20-2!./ng-zorro-antd.less");
          ^
Unrecognised input
      in /Users/shotbyms/Work/Zenhomes-Experiments/ng-ant-design-poc/ant-design-poc/node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.less (line 1, column 12)
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./node_modules/style-loader/dist!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/antd-scss-theme-plugin/build/dist/lib/antdSassLoader.js??ref--19-2!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):

@import "../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.less"; //import ant design style file
^
      Invalid CSS after "v": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"
      in /Users/shotbyms/Work/Zenhomes-Experiments/ng-ant-design-poc/ant-design-poc/src/styles.scss (line 1, column 1)
```

Does anyone have any experience with this? How can I use the theme and use scss with it at the same time?

Appreciate all the help, thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can't import `less` into `scss`. They are not compatible

Comment: You can change the project to process `less` instead of `scss` in the `angular.json` file `"@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }`

Comment: why not just edit the primary colors the the theme.less file?

Comment: @LingVu I tried that. That doesn't work. And that's exactly the point that I need to use them together. I know they're not compatible but is there a way to tell webpack to take my scss styles and variables and convert them into less compatible? My project currently uses scss (and it's a super big project so I cannot switch to less). And Ant Design uses less - so not sure how to approach this

Comment: @shahidfoy Because my project uses scss and I can use less to modify it but then it cannot be integrated with my current structure

Comment: @maham.shahid have you got any alternative way to do the same?

Answer (score 2):

According to your configuration, you missed the part of passing options to the plugin. Here are 2 things you can try:

1. Add the options to the `less-loader` to enable javascript
2. Initialize the plugin with the path of your `theme.scss` file

*./webpack.config.js*

```
{
    module:{
        ...// other rules
        {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader',
                AntdScssThemePlugin.themify({
                    loader: 'less-loader',
                    options: {
                        javascriptEnabled: true,
                        relativeUrls: false,
                    },
                }),
            ],
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        ...// other plugins configurations
        new AntdScssThemePlugin(path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets/theme/theme.scss')),
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This mehthod worked for me 
 can check the documentaion here.

https://ng.ant.design/docs/customize-theme/en

Without schematics#

Create a standalone less file named theme.less in src folder, and add the path of it to the list of styles in angular.json file.

...
  "styles": [
    ...
    "src/theme.less"
    ...
  ]
...
Here is an example of theme.less

The base color is changed to #f5222d in the example below.

// -------- import official less file -----------
@import "../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.less";

// -------- override less var -----------
@primary-color          : #f5222d;

Answer (score 0):

Remove   **@import "../node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.less"; //import ant design style file style.scss** from style.scss

and modify angular.json like this and try

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/ng-zorro-antd.min.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. Yes, this fixes the issue with the build of course but it's not the solution for customizing ant-design theme with scss sadly.